# Pagination on pandas dataframe.to_html()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge pandas dataframe I am converting to html table i.e. `dataframe.to_html()`, its about 1000 rows. Any easy way to use pagination so that I dont have to scroll the whole 1000 rows. Say, view the first 50 rows then click next to see subsequent 50 rows?

Comment: That's an intersesting question indeed! If the "pagination" can be implemented using CSS classes, you can try to use [Style](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html) conditionally (i.e. rows 0-49 - Style: page1, 50-99 - Style: page2, etc.).

Comment: Are you trying to view it within a Jupyter notebook, or as an independent HTML file?

Answer (score 16):

### Update 2022

It seems that there is now a simple and modern solution, using [itables](https://github.com/mwouts/itables).

Installation:

```
pip install itables
```

Basic usage (from the GitHub readme):

```
from itables import show

show(df)
```

Result:
[image: itables result]

There is also a command for displaying all tables in the notebook like this by default.

### Original answer (exporting table to HTML file)

The best solution I can think of involves a couple of external JS libraries: [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) and its [DataTables plugin](https://datatables.net/). This will allow for much more than pagination, with very little effort.

Let's set up some HTML, JS and python:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import webbrowser

base_html = """
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</head><body>%s<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$('table').DataTable({
    "pageLength": 50
});});</script>
</body></html>
"""

def df_html(df):
    """HTML table with pagination and other goodies"""
    df_html = df.to_html()
    return base_html % df_html

def df_window(df):
    """Open dataframe in browser window using a temporary file"""
    with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.html') as f:
        f.write(df_html(df))
    webbrowser.open(f.name)
```

And now we can load a sample dataset to test it:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd

iris = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)

df_window(df)
```

The beautiful result:
[image]

A few notes:

- Notice the `pageLength` parameter in the `base_html` string. This is where I defined the default number of rows per page. You can find other optional parameters in the DataTable [options page](https://datatables.net/manual/options).
- The `df_window` function was tested in a Jupyter Notebook, but should work in plain python as well.
- You can skip `df_window` and simply write the returned value from `df_html` into an HTML file.

**Edit: how to make this work with a remote session (e.g. Colab)**

When working on a remote notebook, like in Colab or Kaggle the temporary file approach won't work, since the file is saved on the remote machine and not accessible by your browser. A workaround for that would be to download the constructed HTML and open it locally (adding to the previous code):

```
import base64
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

my_html = df_html(df)
my_html_base64 = base64.b64encode(my_html.encode()).decode('utf-8')
display(HTML(f'<a download href="data:text/html;base64,{my_html_base64}" target="_blank">Download HTML</a>'))
```

This will result in a link containing the entire HTML encoded as a base64 string. Clicking it will download the HTML file and you can then open it directly and view the table.

Comment: I get error in my notebook while using it. `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @RonakShah, I assume you are using python3. Try adding `mode='w+'` to the `NamedTemporaryFile` parameters and let me know if it works.

Comment: There seems to be some issue from my end which I need to figure out. The code given by you works fine. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I have a question. When I tried to run in google collab I can.t do it. is there any suggestion to get in collab?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GSandro_Strongs I've edited the answer with a solution for you. Let me know how it works.

Comment: @RonakShah thanks for your help, I add this line display(HTML(df_html(df))) and I got the table in the google colab with no necesarry to download.

Comment: Not working for me. It's returning plain table/df when tried on Jupyter. I don't know much about JS and JQuery. Do I need to install anything on my venv to make this work?

Comment: @Darshan - no need to install anything in normal environments. Are you trying the first (local) or second (colab) solution? Any way you can share your code?

Comment: @Shovalt very good answer you posted. Thank you. I was inspired by your answer and (*in my case*), I concatenated the `base_html` to the HTML of the dataframe - `df.to_html()`. I save this result as a file, but also, I did use the result as a local variable called `total_html` and call `display(HTML(total_html))` for display the result. Frankly, I don't know if my approach is a good practice, but, it worked in Google Colab.

Comment: Also, I work on Google Colab with the dark theme enabled, so, the DataTable plugin styles looks a little *odd*- just, if anyone want to try it, you can just customize the CSS styles of the DataTable or leave the Google Colab with the *light* theme - [here is a visual example with Colab's light theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQSSi.png) - and [Colab with dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN1zn.png).

Answer (score 1):

I developed a solution for this out of necessity: [paginate_pandas](https://github.com/jmberros/paginate_pandas), a much simpler package than `itables`, leveraging on `ipywidgets`.

With some obvious bias, I feel `itables` might be a bit overkill. I can already filter and sort with pandas when I'm in Jupyter, so the only thing I need is pagination. **paginate_pandas** gives you that with a nice slider:

[image: paginate pandas example screenshot]