# Pagination on pandas dataframe.to_html() with Large DataFrame

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that needs to be converted to a HTML file.  The DataFrame can be quite large and it contains images.  I saw this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893448/pagination-on-pandas-dataframe-to-html) which works for smaller DataFrames but mine tend to be around 10k-20k rows (with images) so the html file just loads and loads but eventually crashes.

Is there a way to just load the images and text for each page individually rather than the page trying to load everything at once?

Or is there another method for creating a HTML file from a Pandas DataFrame that would work with a large DataFrame containing image tags?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the 'to_html()' method.  Here's an example.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('name of file')
df.to_html('name.htm')
```

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of this, but the resulting html file will not work as the dataframe is too large.  So I need something that wouldn't try to load the whole dataframe at once.  The linked thread uses pagination so it would be nice if I could just load when you go to the next page.